# Angular: is it possible in the result of method in ngIf reuse in yours child item?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I have a problem, is it possible put inside on an element the result of method call in template?
controlError(item.name) method return if there is an error a string with the error else return null

```
<table class="w-100">
  <td *ngFor="let item of form.fields">
    <mat-form-field class="w-100" *ngIf="item.dataType==='string'">
        <mat-label>{{ item.labelDefault | translate}}</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput required formControlName="{{item.name}}">
        <mat-error *ngIf="controlError(item.name)">
          //result of controlError
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</table>
```

if is it possible how to resolve him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `as` construct of the [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive.

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="(controlError(item.name)) as result">
  {{ result }}
</mat-error>
```